# commandSelect always says no open connection

Tags: c#, service, executereader

I have a problem with my c# service.
I tested my program first as a console aplication and everything went fine.
After I made my tests I set up a service and installed the service on my PC.
In the service I want to make a query from a SQL server.
The code snippet can be found here:

```
// Create the Command and Parameter objects.
sQuery = "select count(*) " + sWhere;
eventLog.WriteEntry("Datasets for archive transfer will be calculated by" + sQuery, EventLogEntryType.Information);

commandSelect = new SqlCommand(sQuery, connectionSQL);
connectionSQL.Open();

reader = commandSelect.ExecuteReader();
```

But everytime it comes to the commandSelect.ExecuteReader() I get an error that there is no open connection. I added a lot of logging to see if the connection is closed and also added the explicit open() command but I can not get it up and running.
Anyone any idea about this? What is the big and obviously secret difference between a console program an d a service at this point?

Thanks
Matthias

Comment: Use `using`-statements. I see already three missing. That can cause such issues if the pool needs to open always a new physical connection if the last was not closed properly. I hope `connectionSQL` isn't static.

Comment: Is the service using the same credentials to connect to the database as your console application?